# Create a UIView Subclass that calls a delegate function whenever it's parent viewController appears?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

**EDIT 2: I now think the best soluton is to create ListeningView.h that just includes a ListeningView protocol, instead of subclassing ListeningView (since we can't do multiple inheritance in Obj-C). Then, you still need ListeningViewController as well.**

**EDIT: Ok, I figured out what the approved idiom is here. I should subclass UIViewController to create ResponderViewController, which will loop through its subviews for ResponderViews when it appears/disappears. Then, any viewController that has responderViews should inherit from ResponderViewController.**

=======

UIViewControllers have viewWillAppear, viewDidDisappear, etc. delegate methods.

I would like to create a UIView subclass that can be added to a viewController's view, and when that UIViewController apears or disappears, a delegate function is called.

I could easily do this by putting function calls in the UIViewController viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear delegate functions, but how can I encapsulate this behavior in the UIView?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do that if I were you. All that sort of behavior *should not* be controlled by a view; that's just was controllers are for.

Comment: These views will not be fullscreen views, so I don't think I should use a UIViewController here. None of its methods would work properly to present or hide the view. If there was a class called PartialScreenViewController that could be added to a viewController and have all of its delegate methods called, that's what I'd use.

Comment: A ViewController is supposed to control all it's sub-views not just the ones that fill the screen. I have view controllers that control dozens of sub-views none of which fill the screen. Jonathan is right, this work should be done in the controller not a view.